# Converting sequence of ASCII codes as integers into a string

Tags: python, string, list, integer, ascii

I have a sequence of ASCII codes, i.e.

```
[47, 104, 111, 109, 101, 47, 100, 105, 116, 122, 101, 108, 47, 114, 97, 100, 97, 114, 47, 100, 97, 116, 97, 47, 114, 101, 99, 111, 114, 100, 105, 110, 103, 115, 47, 112, 101, 110, 100, 101, 108, 46, 104, 53]
```

which is supposed to encode a filename in string format. How can I obtain the string representation in python?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `chr(x)` to convert ascii codes as integers back to strings.

```
>>> l=[47, 104, 111, 109, 101, 47, 100, 105, 116, 122, 101, 108, 47, 114, 97, 100, 97, 114, 47, 100, 97, 116, 97, 47, 114, 101, 99, 111, 114, 100, 105, 110, 103, 115, 47, 112, 101, 110, 100, 101, 108, 46, 104, 53]
>>> ''.join([chr(x) for x in l])
'/home/ditzel/radar/data/recordings/pendel.h5'
```